# How to zoom in on a marker in a map activity in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, zooming

Hi I wanted to know how I can slowly zoom in on a marker in a map activity in android. Currently my app just opens zoomed in on the marker. I would like it to zoom in slowly when the app is opened.

This is my current code

```
LatLng mark = new LatLng(21.197384, 6.369441);
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mark).title("Marker for Mark"));
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mark));
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mark, zoomLevel));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mMap.animateCamera` instead of `mMap.moveCamera`

Also, you can [control the duration of the movement](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#public-methods) using

```
animateCamera (CameraUpdate update, int durationMs, GoogleMap.CancelableCallback callback)
```

In your example, change

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mark));
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mark, zoomLevel));
```

for

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mark, zoomLevel));
```

or, if you want the movement to last 200ms:

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mark, zoomLevel), 200, null);
```

Comment: sorry I get a bunch of errors when I used the above codes which say cannot resolve CameraUpdate and cannot resolve callback

Answer (score 1):

Try `mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mark, zoomLevel));` instead of

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mark));
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mark, zoomLevel));
```

Answer (score 1):

In this way you can achieve this --

```
CameraUpdate center= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(latitude_origin, longitude_origin));
CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude_origin, longitude_origin),3);
  googleMap.animateCamera(center);
  googleMap.animateCamera(zoom);
```

Hope this helps!